# Grouping same instances of a field in a grouped bar chart - CHART.JS

Tags: javascript, sql, chart.js

I have the following SQL query:

```
select datetime,name,amount
from users
where datetime in ('20180730 060000','20180731 060000','20180801 060000')
group by datetime, name
order by datetime
```

I want to group same instances of dates in a grouped bar chart (e.g. if datetime is 20180730 060000 for 3 rows, the chart.js will display a grouped bar according to the names related to datetime).

We are currently storing the SQL values in an JSON array. The Javascript file contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
             url:***,
             method: "GET",
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 var DATETIME= [];
                 console.log(DATETIME);
                 var AMOUNT= [];

                 for(var i in data){
                     DATETIME.push(" " + data[i].DATETIME);
                     AMOUNT.push(data[i].AMOUNT);
                 }

                 var chartdata = {
                     labels: DATETIME,
                     datasets: [{   
                         label : '',
                         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)',
                         borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                         hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                         hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                         data: AMOUNT
                     }]
                 };
                 var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                 var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                     type: 'bar',
                     data: chartdata
                     });
             },
             error:  function(data){
                 console.log(data);
             }
    });
});
```

This is the output of the array:

```
[{"DATETIME":"20180730 060000","NAME":"JOE","AMOUNT":"5132"},
{"DATETIME":"20180730 060000","NAME":"ALAN","AMOUNT":"4603"},
{"DATETIME":"20180730 060000","NAME":"MARK","AMOUNT":"21391"},
{"DATETIME":"20180731 060000","NAME":"JOE","AMOUNT":"6492"},
{"DATETIME":"20180731 060000","NAME":"ALAN","AMOUNT":"8014"},
{"DATETIME":"20180731 060000","NAME":"MARK","AMOUNT":"27829"},
{"DATETIME":"20180801 060000","NAME":"JOE","AMOUNT":"6821"},
{"DATETIME":"20180801 060000","NAME":"ALAN","AMOUNT":"6938"},
{"DATETIME":"20180801 060000","NAME":"MARK","AMOUNT":"11961"}]
```

[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzPg4.png)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new at this :) just edited the question.

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: I want to group the same DATETIME fields in one grouped bar. Each coloured bar will be associated to a name (e.g. 20180730 060000 will be divided for JOE, ALAN and MARK)